# How do I use tcp_diag with C++?

Tags: c++, linux, tcp

I've googled this all over the place, and I'm still at a loss. tcp_diag is supposed to replace /proc/net/tcp, but I can't find a shred of documentation on how to use it. Please tell me how to #include it, and what methods, classes and functions it has. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a DGRAM socket with domain AF_NETLINK and protocol NETLINK_INET_DIAG. Then you use the netlink protocol to communicate with the kernel and get the information you need.

Further reading:

- http://kristrev.github.io/2013/07/26/passive-monitoring-of-sockets-on-linux
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356
- https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/tree/misc/ss.c

Answer (score 2):

The tcp_diag kernel module does not supply C or C++ functions to call.  It provides its interface by causing certain special "files" like /proc/net/tcp to exist.  You can get that information directly by reading that file as an ordinary file, or with an executable tool such as `ss` or the older `netstat`.

Comment: Thanks! This was bugging me to no end!

Comment: Actually, I have found out that it uses netlink to communicate with userspace.